# How to execute a clip.preview() with moviepy.editor and a while loop simultaneously

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, python-multithreading, moviepy

My goal is that when you press space whenever `idle.preview()` is shown, it plays another video (`end.preview()`). It would repeat the movie until space is pressed.
But `preview()` takes the whole video to execute, so I used multiprocessing and threads
to have it and the while loop `if keyboard.is_pressed` to execute parallelly, but even with it, I have to wait for the preview to finish before being able to press space... I tried to put the while loop in a function and put it in a second thread/process, but it gives the same result... And with Process, the script restart from the beginning when the preview finishes, even when I put the `if __name__ = __main__` before `Process(target=idle()).start()`. How could I reach my goal ?

```
from moviepy.editor import *
import keyboard
from multiprocessing import Process

    def Comp(p_start, p_idle, p_end):
        start = VideoFileClip(path % (drive, p_start))
        end = VideoFileClip(path % (drive, p_end))
        idle = VideoFileClip(path % (drive, p_idle))
        print('start playing')
        start.preview(fps=60)
        print('start playing end')

        def idle():
            idle = VideoFileClip(path % (drive, p_idle))
            print('idle playing')
            idle.preview(fps=60)
            print('idle playing end')
        start.close()
        Process(target=idle()).start()
        while True:
            if keyboard.is_pressed('space'):
                pygame.mixer.music.load('%s\...\Continue.wav' % drive)
                pygame.mixer.music.play()
                print('music played')
                break

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        Comp('Title incoming.mp4', 'Title incoming.mp4', 'Title incoming.mp4')
```

Note: My code is in a try-except block.